# How add new line after each iteration in thymeleaf?

Tags: html, thymeleaf, each

How can I add new line after each iteration in thymeleaf? 
th:each generated content is rendered on a single line.

```
<div th:each="table: ${mapEntry.value}">
    <div>
        <span th:text="${table}"></span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with using `<br>` or `<hr>` tag before each statement finish.

```
<div th:each="table: ${mapEntry.value}">
    <div>
        <span th:text="${table}"></span>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

mrtasln is correct. Even you can add one more `<div>&nbsp;</div>` or set some stylesheet with `adding padding / margins for bottom`.

```
<div th:each="table: ${mapEntry.value}">
    <div>
        <span th:text="${table}"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```